# MySQL INSERT multiple rows ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... WHERE EXISTS(subquery)

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I want to insert values for multiple rows into a table. Also, in case of duplicate, the query must be able to update those rows. But I want to check also if user have access to write into `mytable` using a subquery. How can I do that in one command?

Not working example because MySQL INSERT [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) does not support the WHERE clause:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
(1, 2, 3),
(4, 5, 6),
(7, 8, 9)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2), col3=VALUES(col3)
WHERE EXISTS (subquery_to_verify_if_user_can_write_into_mytable);
```

For a single row it can look like this (working example but inserting just one row, not multiple rows):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM accesstable WHERE my_condition_to_check_if_user_can_write_into_mytable LIMIT 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2), col3=VALUES(col3)
```

But I want to insert values for multiple rows.
PS Nice -1 in first minute :))

**LATER EDIT**

This is an ugly solution. Creating a table with desired values with a false `dumb` column and join with a fake table made from interrogating for user access:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3
FROM (
    SELECT 1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3, 0 dumb
    UNION SELECT 4, 5, 6, 0
    UNION SELECT 7, 8, 9, 0
    ) t1
JOIN (SELECT 0 dumb FROM accesstable WHERE user_id=114 LIMIT 1) t2
ON t1.dumb=t2.dumb
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2), col3=VALUES(col3)
```

Does anyone have a better idea? I'm quite a beginner in databases. I'm interested in the simplest and quickest solution. Creating an entire fake column and make a JOIN it seems to me quite expensive operations and not quite elegant.

**IMPROVED JOIN** thanks @Nick:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT t1.*
FROM ((
    SELECT 1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3
    UNION SELECT 4, 5, 6
    UNION SELECT 7, 8, 9
    ) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 FROM accesstable WHERE user_id=114 LIMIT 1) t2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2), col3=VALUES(col3)
```

Comment: "also have access to table", what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: I have another table that holds informations about the access for that user. Someting like 'accesstable ' that holds informations like "user with id x can write into mytable?"

Comment: Is there any way for you to make the SQL's more ... real? Like not using col1, col2, col3, mytable, etc.? Every layer of abstraction away from the real problem makes your question harder to understand and to answer.

Comment: What happened when you tried your query?

Comment: MySQL INSERT Syntax does not support the WHERE clause. [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: What column is your key on? And what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7.25. My table use a PRIMARY key ID (not used in query). Also table use an UNIQUE INDEX combining multiple columns.

Comment: @Junior note that the extra set of parentheses in my query are necessary because otherwise MySQL thinks the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is the start of an JOIN condition and gives a syntax error when it gets to `KEY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would maintain access rights in the application layer and only execute the `INSERT` query *if* the user had those access rights. If you must do it solely in MySQL your last query is pretty much your only alternative, although it can be simplified (and made more efficient) by using a `CROSS JOIN`; this way you don't need the dummy column as all rows of the `UNION` table will be automatically joined to the single row from the access check (assuming it returns data). Note in my query I've added the `id` key column for demo purposes:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT t1.*
FROM ((
       SELECT 2 id, 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3
       UNION SELECT 1, 4, 5, 6
       UNION SELECT 3, 7, 8, 9
      ) t1
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 FROM accesstable WHERE user_id=114 LIMIT 1) t2
     )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2), col3=VALUES(col3)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3dd200b7117e5562fd4e8c416c6c634e)

Comment: Thank you four your time and effort. CROSS JOIN is better. And yes, I want to be sure that (in EXACT moment I add new data in table) the user have access because I add also his ID and other stuff in mytable and it is important to have clean tables.